# How to make field act like a table

Tags: mysql

Sorry but I couldn't find/search for specific "thing"

so.

I have tables

```
users(id , name , kills , .... ) ;
quests( id , name , description , enemy_id , n_to_kill , en_killed , used_id );
```

what I want to achieve is for all users to have separate quests table.
I don't understand how it's possible but I think it should be(?)

example:

```
users:{ 1 , admin , 7 } { 2 , user , 11 } { 3 , john , 0 }
quests:{ 1 , "killall" , "kill all" , 0 , 100 , 0 , ??}
```

so to save for each user how many quests he finished/killed x out of y

Is it even possible?

Thanks for reading...

Comment: I don't understand the question.. isn't that what you already have ?

Comment: you don't need separate tables. Use on quests table. Have a column called UserID which matches the ID in the users table. Create a Foreign Key between them. If you read a tutorial on database design this sort of design point will become much easier to understand.

Comment: If an user can have `1-to-many` quests, but a single quest cannot belong to `0-to-many` users, then, please check [how foreign keys work](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) it is exactly why its intended for.